# Autofocus is not working in flutter textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

if caneditfoldername==true i wanna show a textfield else i wannna show a text..but the focus in textfield isnt working..can anyone fix it?

code:   appBar: AppBar(
actions: [
IconButton(

```
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          caneditfoldername = true;
                          FocusScope.of(context)
                              .requestFocus(foldertitlefocus);
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.edit_rounded,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .028,
                      )))
             
        ],
    
        title: widget.two == false
            ? Text(
                "Add",
               
              )
            :
            caneditfoldername == true ? Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(right:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .23,),
              child: TextFormField(
                
          
                  focusNode: foldertitlefocus,
                 
                 autofocus: true,
                 
                  controller: foldertitle,
                 
                 
            ):Text(
                 "My passwords..",
                  
            )
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `TextFormField` widget is not closed properly, try to modify:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  actions: [
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          caneditfoldername = true;
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(foldertitlefocus);
        });
      },
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.edit_rounded,
        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .028,
      ),
    ),
  ],
  title: widget.two == false
      ? Text(
          "Add",
        )
      : caneditfoldername == true
          ? Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .23,
              ),
              child: TextFormField(
                focusNode: foldertitlefocus,
                autofocus: true,
                controller: foldertitle,
              ),
            )
          : Text(
              "My passwords..",
            ),
),
```

Comment: i happy to see your respond..but i have closed that and its just an example of my code..